# XSL Ignoring Elements that are Blank or Equal to 0

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm doing an XSLT Transformation and I want to ignore elements that have a value of zero as well as elements that are blank. A sample of the XML I am using is shown below

```
<row>
 <col1>a</col1>
 <col2></col2>
 <col3>0</col3>
</row>
```

For example, I have tried using:

```
<xsl:if test="col2 != '0' or col2 != ' '><xsl:value-of select="col2"/></xsl:if>
```

but it to filter out everything instead of just filtering the data that are blank or zero. But this doesn't work. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: For future reference, rather than saying "this doesn't work", you need to explain exactly what is happening. Are you getting an error message? Is nothing being output, or something else you don't expect? Showing your actual output and your expected output would help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing incorrectly is that you are using an `or` instead of an `and`. Additionally, you are also checking for a single space, not an empty element. So, if you consider spaces as 'blanks' you should use the `normalize-space` function

```
<xsl:if test="col2 != '0' and normalize-space(col2) != ''">
```

Note, depending on what you are actually trying to achieve, it may probably be better to use template matching here, instead of `xsl:if`

Try this for example

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[. != '0' and normalize-space(.) != '']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, you can use a 'pull' approach, and write template to ignore empty elements (as opposed to specifically selecting the ones you want to copy). This would also work

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="row/*[. = '0' or normalize-space(.) = '']" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test is a classic tautology: x!=a or x!=b is always true, because when x=a then the second proposition is true, when x=b then the first proposition is true, and when x=c, both are true. In terms of logic, you need to write x!=a AND x!=b.

In terms of XSLT, if col2 is supposed to be a non-zero numeric value, you could formulate your test as:

```
<xsl:if test="number(col2)">
```

I am not sure in what context you are testing this; usually it's best to eliminate the unwanted elements **before** having to deal with them, for example by:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="col2[boolean(number(.))]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out this one

```
  <xsl:for-each select="row/*">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)!=''">
      <xsl:if test=".!='0'">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>               
  </xsl:for-each>
```